# string reverse without new array

Tags: c, string, arrays

hi can anybody tell me the error in this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[]="abcdefgh";
    int i=0;
    int n=strlen(a);
    char *first;
    char *second;
    char *c;
    *first=a[0];
    *second=a[7];
    for(i=0;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
            *c=*first;
            *first=*second;
            *second=*c;
            first++;
            second--;
    }

    for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
            printf("%c",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No one is going to help you dig through that mess. Put a little effort in and format it decently.

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what the error is?

Comment: I'm just gonna say it's homework, forgive me if it's not. Also, I'm glad you've attempted the problem before asking for help, kudos. That said, when you're getting an error it's important to tell us what that error is. If it's not a compile error, tell us the result you're getting and what you wanted instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is these lines:

```
*first=a[0];
*second=a[7];
```

I think what you want is to get `first` and `second` to point to the correct elements, which is:

```
first = &a[0]; // address of the first element
second = &a[7]; // address of the eighth element
```

What you have is assigning the value of `a[0]` to the address pointed to by `first`, which is not initialized. Also, you might as well use `n - 1` instead of 7 here, so you don't hardcode the size. Also these lines:

```
*c=*first;
*first=*second;
*second=*c;
```

You see, the pointer `c` also hasn't been initialized. What you should do is not have `c` as a pointer:

```
char c;
```

Then use it just like a normal variable:

```
c = *first;
*first = *second;
*second = c;
```

And just a design note, you don't need the counter/for-loop. Rather, you know you're done with `second` is <= to `first` (that is, we're at or have crossed the half-way point):

```
while (second > first)
```

Lastly, through some spaces in there! Your code is very condensed and hard to read. Don't be afraid to space things out.

Comment: GMan, you da man. Fix first and complain later… you must be a blessing to your office.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Heh, thank you. :) No office yet, still in school. :P @Codeguru: No problem. If you find your problem solved, click the check mark on the answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, he's a blessing to me, GMan taught me C++ and continues to help improve my coding abilities. He's an excellent classmate :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    *first=a[0];
```

The pointer `first` isn’t initialized, so you’re assigning to invalid memory.